# JQUERY: selecting a dropdown based on submitted values

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have a dropdown which you choose one of three values

```
<select id="FilterType" name="FilterType">
  <option value=''>All</option>
  <option value="LanCode">Lan Code</option>
  <option value="SupportTeamName">Support Team</option>
</select>
```

based on what the user chooses another dropdown is created beside that one
it will have a bunch of `<option value="8">Something</option>` then the user submits the form back to itself

I have written a function to set the first dropdown to the submitted value and then repopulate the second dropdown according to the submitted value and then select the item in the dropdown passed to the page...

```
$('#FilterType').find("option[value*='<%= Request.QueryString("FilterType") %>']").attr('selected','selected');     
getFilter();
$("#<%= findselect %> option[value='<%= findoption %>']").attr('selected',true);
```

Now the problem is I can't seem set the item selected in the second dropdown. I guess it's because the page is loaded and then the second dropdown is created

How can I set the second dropdown to the value submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can move your "select logic" and
  put it right next the "create logic" `CreateSecondDD(); SelectSecondDD();`
- Another thing you can do is move your
  "select logic" just after the end of
  the  tag, this way the script
  will be called just after page
  finishes reloading. `</body> <script> SelectSecondDD(); </script>`

But what i really recommend you to do is, when creating DOM for the Second Dropdown, always check the value from first DropDown, and apply the required selected attribute.

This task is quite easy using [jQuery DOM plugi](http://mg.to/2006/02/27/easy-dom-creation-for-jquery-and-prototype)n.

Comment: thanks I needed a second pair of eyes to look at it
I used asp to set a js variable at run time with the value to select 
if it existed i used the ajax return on the second dropdown to preselect the one i needed